# How to import Stdlib and other to your programm? (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar

So i have read how to implement an external JAR to my libraries, i downloaded it and put it in my java build path. And it shows: stdlib.jar and below: JRE System Library.

But i cant find the code of actually importing that in the threat. I tried: import Std; which unsuprisingly was wrong.
Where can i find the "name" of that thing i want to import?

For example i know : java.util.Scanner but i just cant find where it is located.

Sry for such a stupid question but im just getting started with java.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSOsF.png)

Comment: There are many classes within the stdlib.jar library. Which ones are you trying to access?: `import stdlib.StdIn;` or `import stdlib.StdOut;` or `import static stdlib.StdIn.readLine;` or `import static stdlib.StdOut.println;`, etc.

Comment: All of it :D, is there a link where i can see the names of the classes?

Comment: But most importantly Draw

Comment: [Here is a list of all the classes](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) which are links to their source code. If you look below the list I believe it tells you how to install the library :)

Comment: Well i added  what u suggested but it cant find it. i added a picture of my screen. Hope this does help a bit.

Comment: What are you drawing onto? You haven't established that. Try this before drawing your triangle: `StdDraw.setCanvasSize(500, 500);`. Then: `StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.WHITE);`. [Read this](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis110/15su/lectures/10stddraw.pdf).